# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error when trying to use Google's Assistant SDK with RPi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to use Google Assistant SDK for the Raspberry Pi 3. I managed to install everything correctly, and the date is perfectly correct. However, when I try to Authorize the Google Assistant SDK sample, I get the error described in the title. It can't verify the certificate.

When I use `date`, the result is `Thu Jun 29 17:16:42 CST 2017`, which is very much correct at the time I use it. I am located in Costa Rica.

This is the complete error output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 844, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 325, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 364, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 577, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 804, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 630, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/bin/google-oauthlib-tool", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/tool/__main__.py", line 106, in main
    creds = flow.run_console()
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 358, in run_console
    self.fetch_token(code=code)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 235, in fetch_token
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 221, in fetch_token
    verify=verify, proxies=proxies)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 549, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 360, in request
    headers=headers, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 502, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 612, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found a guide saying the following dependencies are required. This fixed it for me.

```
sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
```